# Add angular app built with CLI into existing webpack project

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am working on an existing project which used webpack for front end asset compilation. I would like to add an angular app to this project. The angular app will be contained to a specific part of the site initially. Ideally I would like to use the CLI for the build but it isn't clear in the docs whether I can run the angular CLI commands within my existing `webpack.config.js`.

My folder directly is roughly as follows. Webpack imports from the webpack driectory and outputs the assets into an assets directory.

```
/
|-/webpack
  |-/webpack-module-1
  |-/another-module
  |-/some-other-webpack-module
 [|- IDEALLY ANGULAR-CLI APP WOULD GO HERE]
|-/assets
  |-/js
  |-/css
|-webpack.config.js
|-package.json
```

Is there a way of importing angular-cli app into webpack config?

#### Update

As a workaround I am using concurrently to run the angular-cli commands alongside the webpack ones and updated the `outputPath` of the angular app. I'm going to leave the question open in the hope somebody has a more elegant solution.